# Wireshark : TCP Connection Establishment

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packets

- In TCP Connection Establishment, When a SYN segment (TCP segment with
  only SYN flag enabled) flows from the sender/client to
  receiver/server the wirehsark shows the window size. But the window
  size is supposed to be present only when the Acknowledgement flag is
  set since it is the value normally referred to as receiver window and
  is determined by the receiver.
- Until the client sends the SYN segment the server will not able to report the receiver window to the sender.
- Since the window size is present in wireshark for the SYN segment, does that mean the value of window size could be junk for the SYN segment.
- If not what's the use of window size in the SYN segment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP is a full duplex protocol i.e. data can travel in both directions. Each end of the TCP connection must advertise a receive window to the other end to say how much buffer space it has available to receive data.

In terms of how useful the window size advertisement is in a SYN packet, not much unless TCP is doing a [fast open](http://lwn.net/Articles/508865/) where the server can send data before the ACK of the three-way handshake and therefore must abide by the window advertisement in the SYN.